# How to change title in for loop with different nc files?

Tags: python, arrays, for-loop, time, python-xarray

I have 49 .nc files that I want to plot (map). These nc files are from a atmospheric simulation. the variable I am interested in is "foot" or footprints, with lon, lat, time (73 times). I summed up times to get a 2D map. Now I am trying to map out all the 49 maps with titles reflecting location of simulation + time of simulation. However, I get no title at all.

I have tried plt.title('location' + Time[i]) before for one nc file and it worked. However, I am having trouble with doing the same with multiple files. What is wrong?

```
file_list= sorted(glob.glob('*.nc'))

a_foot = None 
Time = []
Foot= []
for file in sorted(glob.glob('*.nc')):
    #print(file)
    data= xr.open_dataset(file)
    lon= data['lon']
    lat= data['lat']
    time= data['time']
    foot= data['foot']
    
    if a_foot is None:
        a_foot=foot 
    else:
        a_foot = foot
    data.close()            
    #print(a_foot.data.min())
    #print(a_foot.data.max())   
    
    for num in time:
        actual_time= time.dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
        Time.append(actual_time)
        
for i in Time:        
    ax= plt.axes(projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())
    levels= [0.01, 0.05, 0.1, 0.15, 0.20, 0.25, 0.30, 0.35, 0.40, 0.45, 0.50, 0.55, 0.60]
    plt.contourf(a_foot['lon'], a_foot['lat'],a_foot.sum(dim='time'), 
                 levels=levels,
                 colors= ['mediumblue', 'deepskyblue', 'aqua', 'lightseagreen', 'mediumseagreen', 'limegreen', 'yellow', 'gold', 'orange', 'darkorange', 'tomato', 'orangered', 'red'], 
                 ) #when _r is added to cmap is used, it means reversed color pattern
    ax.set_extent([-150, -143, 57.5, 72])
    ax.coastlines()
    gls= ax.gridlines(draw_labels=True)
    gls.top_labels=False   # suppress top labels
    gls.right_labels=False # suppress right labels
    plt.colorbar(label='Footprints, ppm (umol-1 m2 s)',location= 'right', shrink=0.5, format='%.0e', extend= "both")
    #Add a marker at the receptor location
    ax.plot(-146.231483, 64.054333, marker='o', markerfacecolor="None", markeredgecolor='black', markersize=6 )
    plt.title('location,' + Time[i] )
    plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

At no point are you setting i as a value so it would always be 0.
Try declaring it as a variable and incrementing it with the loop

Comment: Hello Thank you for your answer. Yes, I did that, but there are no title at all.. I just edited the code on here.

Comment: Ok so `i in Time` will give you the value of `i = Time[n]` so when you are calling `Time[i]` later to set the title you are actually calling `Time[Time[n]]` you should either set `plt.title('location, ' + i)` or set i to be `for i in range(Time) plt.title('location, ' + Time[i])` - does that make sense?

Comment: You could also delcare i as an actual variable outside of the loop and increment it inside the loop but it would only achieve the same result with less readability

Comment: Yes, it makes sense. When I try the first solution, I get "ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()";  and when I try the second solution I get "TypeError: 'list' object cannot be interpreted as an integer". I also tried the "for i in range(len(Time)) and got an error as well. I also tried Foot= np.arange(0,49) then looping my maps through that, but it is not working. I'm stuck and not understanding why..

Comment: This works for me using the gmtime and strftime from the time module:

    `for i in range(50):`
        `time = strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", gmtime())`
        `plt.title('location,' + time)`
        `plt.show()`

Comment: Thank you for helping. Still not working...

Comment: I figured it out.. I had to use plt.title('location' + str(actual_time[0].values)). Thank you so much for helping!

Comment: No problem. Glad you got it sorted!